# How to get all files from a directory using javafx

Tags: file, javafx, directory, loading, fxml

I'm new on JavaFx and I can't manage to get all the files from a directory (I need to display some pictures using an interface built with javafx). I've been trying to use listFiles() but I keep on getting null when displayed to test.
Here's the code :

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable{

    private String path;
    private ArrayList<File> files;
    private String[] extens;

    @FXML
    public Polygon right_arrow;
    public Polygon left_arrow;
    public Button edit_button;
    public ImageView home_button;
    public TextField search_box;
    public TextArea tag_box;
    public ChoiceBox language_box;
    public Label photo_title;
    public Label photo_number;
    public ImageView photo_box;
    public Image home_picture;

    public void goToEditPage (ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Edit.fxml"));

            Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));
            stage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void goToHomePage (){
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("home.fxml"));

            Parent root1 = fxmlLoader.load();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));
            stage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public Image getPicture(){


        /*home_picture = new Image(String.valueOf(getClass().getResource("home.png")));
        */return home_picture;
    }

    private void photo (String pathGet){
        path = pathGet;
        files = new ArrayList<File>();

        File repo = new File (path);

        File[] fileList = repo.listFiles();
        for (int i=0; i<1; i++) {
            System.out.println(repo.list());
        }
       // System.out.println(fileList.length);
        /*int nb = fileList.length;
        String ext = "";
        int s = -1;

        for (int i=0; i<nb; i++){
            if (fileList[i].isFile()){
                s = fileList[i].getName().lastIndexOf(".");
                if (s>-1) {
                    ext = fileList[i].getName().substring(s + 1);
                }
                if (ext=="jpg"||ext=="png"||ext=="jpeg"){
                    files.add(fileList[i]);
                }
            }
        }*/
    }


    public File getPhotoById(int id) {
        id--;
        return this.files.get(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        photo("sample/photos/album_1");
        //photo_box.setImage(new Image(files.get(1).toURI().toString()));
    }
}
```

I think I don't use listFiles() the proper way but I can't figure out how to actually do so.
My folder album_1 contains 3 pictures in .png. However when I try this sample, I get nothing as a result, as if the folder was empty.
I hope someone will be able to help me.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `for` loop is wrong. The proper way to iterate through the list of files that is returned is

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < fileList.length ; i++) {
    System.out.println(filesList[i]);
}
```

or (better):

```
for (File f : fileList) {
    System.out.println(f);
}
```

Note that the [documentation for `listFiles()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles--) says:

> An array of abstract pathnames denoting the files and directories in
>   the directory denoted by this abstract pathname. The array will be
>   empty if the directory is empty. Returns null if this abstract
>   pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.

So if you are receiving a null pointer exception here, it's because `repo` is not a directory. You probably want to check first:

```
if (repo.isDirectory()) {
    File[] fileList = repo.listFiles();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: thank you I'm going to try this I didnt check if that was a directory sorry :/

Comment: Hi @James_D, I use the `.isDirectory()` method, but it doesn't work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45292932/javafx-isdirectory-not-returning-true