# JavaFX - `isDirectory` Not Returning TRUE

Tags: file, javafx, directory

Why is this check not return true?

```
    String dirpath = getClass().getResource("../util/assets/sounds/").toString();
    File dir = new File(dirpath);
    System.out.println(dirpath);
    System.out.println(dir);
    System.out.println(dir.isDirectory());
```

It returns these:

```
file:/D:/JAVA/exercises/FX/TasksList/build/classes/taskslist/util/assets/sounds
file:\D:\JAVA\exercises\FX\TasksList\build\classes\taskslist\util\assets\sounds
false
```

I run it using netbeans IDE as a source code.

Comment: How is your app packaged, is it in a jar file?  If so, then the resource will use the jar protocol, not the file protocol.  If you print the string `getClass().getResource("../util/assets/sounds/").toString()`, what does it return?

Comment: @jewelsea please see the edit..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[getClass().getResource(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) returns a [URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html), not a file path string.  [A file path string](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File-java.lang.String-) is needed by the constructor of File.

You can try using the [Paths constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get-java.net.URI-) to construct a valid file path from a [URI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html), which you can get from the resource using [`toUri()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#toURI--).

So, this should work:

```
Files.isDirectory(
    Paths.get(
        getClass().getResource("../util/assets/sounds/").toUri()
    )
)
```

Or

```
new File(
    getClass().getResource("../util/assets/sounds/").toUri()
).isDirectory();
```

I haven't got a windows machine to try that on.

Note: If you start packaging your app as jar (as is recommended), then this technique will break.  The resource would not be a file, but instead a jar resource.  There is no concept of a file directory in relation to a jar resource.

Answer (score 0):

It supposed to be :

`String dirpath = getClass().getResource("../util/assets/sounds/").getPath();`

instead of:

`String dirpath = getClass().getResource("../util/assets/sounds/").toString();`

And it will work.

Comment: Be careful of using this.  If the path contains items which are url encoded (for example a space encoded as `%20`), then it may break.